# when to use ES6 class and when to use function in javascript

Tags: javascript, es6-class

As ES6 has arrived with class.
So i want to know that when to use class and when to use simple function
in javascript.

As function also capable to make new object.

Comment: You use `class` when you need a class (constructor function with prototype object). You use `function` when you need some other function.

Answer (score 9):

Js `Class` is just syntactic sugar for

```
function SomeClass() {
    // this is basically a constructor
    this.property = 'some value';
};

SomeClass.prototype.someMethod = function() {
    // here you define method logic
}
```

If you use Babel or Typescript or you simply don't care for browser interoperabitility, you can use `class` notation, because its simpler to write, but in the essence, nothing changes.

> As function also capable to make new object.

In JS everything but primitives (boolean, number) is created from `Object` so everytrhing even `Array`, `String` or `{}` or `Function` is capable of create new object, but not in the meaning of OOP languages like Java or C#.

You see, JS is prototypical language. Every object has special member called `prototype`. If you invoke `someObject.someMember`, the `someMember` is searched in `someObject` and if it isn't found there, the engine looks in `someObject.protoype`, where's typycally some `previousObject`. You could say, that `someObject` is subclass of `previousObject`, because it reference `previousObject` as its `prototype`. It's different from OOP languages, but it works almost the same way, as subclassing.

You can make new object from any object like this

```
var newObject = {};
newObject.prototype = previousObject;
```

or

```
var newObject = Object.create(previousObject);
```

or

```
function newObject () { ... }
newObject.prototype = previousObject;
```

or

```
class newObject extends previousObject { ... }
```